# how to send and receive data between phonegap child browser to main application

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a Facebook login authentication in a Phonegap child browser. For that externally I have a page that can initiate authentication process and redirects back after authentication (let's say www.mysite.com/Facebook.html). Now I have authentic user from Facebook, but how can I get that authentic user data from child browser to main application and close child browser. for security reason, I set "showLocationBar: false" , so there is no close button.

So, now let me know

- how can I get Facebook authenticated user data (user email and access token for further transactions with Facebook) to main application and close child browser.
- how to close child browser from child browser as I don't have close button on Child-browser.
- is there any way to save data from Facebook to a JavaScript object in my main application

This is my first application with Phonegap, but im experienced with Facebook and JavaScript. So , please let me know if I'm wrong any where.

Thanks in advance, 
Looking forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using chilldbrowser for Facebook connect. Here is the link for complete source code for Facebook connect using childbrowser: http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88. You can get user's name using access_token using the code below:

```
 var params='access_token='+accessToken;
 $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me",params, 
            function(response){
                fbUesrName=response.name;
                },"json");
```

You can close the childbrowser using:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm already done with this one by listening to onLoctionChange Events. But, window.plugins.childBrowser.close() is not closing my child browser in my case some how. do you have any idea about what im missing in this. Please let me know any other way to close child browser from child Browser itself automatically if there area any.

Comment: Which version of phonegap you are using. I am using cordova 2.0.0. It is working fine for me. And even the source code in this link: http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88 also working for me. Does Childbrowser get opened for the given URL? Try with a simple url like https://www.google.co.in/ once.

Comment: @Aswini: i just added an edit to my question. here my question is how to close child browser from childbrowser itself but not from parent PG Application. and regarding link you provided its not encouraged to use external plugins as they are not supported by phonegap build service, so im not using fbconect plugin. So, let me know how to close child browser by clicking a button on child browser, if any. Thanks for Comment here.

Comment: @Venkat Krishna Prasad Chintama: Sorry I am not getting what you are telling."how to close child browser from childbrowser itself" means what? You just want to close the childbrowser right? when you close it, your previous page from where you opened the childbrowser will appear.

Answer (score 0):

@Venkat :  Not sure if you already got the answer for closing child browser from within app. This code worked for me. Put a close button on your site and put the URL as "google.com".From PG app you can write the code below

```
       window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(locationLink){
    if (locationLink.indexOf('google.com') > 0) {
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
              }
      }
```